Can we find a Jouanolou device for $\mathbb{P}^d$ having dimension $<2d$?
Let us work over an algebraically closed field $k$.
A Jouanolou device for a $k$-variety $X$ is an affine space fiberation $f:Y\to X$ such that $Y$ is an affine scheme. (The condition on $f$ means that $X$ has an open covering $\{U_i\}_i$
such that for each $i$, $f^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i$ is isomorphic to the first projection $U_i\times \mathbb{A}^n\to U_i$ over $U_i$ for some $n$.) Jouanolou proved that any quasi-projective $k$-scheme has a Jouanolou device; Thomanson also showed that it is true for smooth $k$-schemes.
In particular, Jouanolou gave an explicit affine space fiberation $Y\to \mathbb{P}^d$  with $Y$ affine of dimension $2d$ (recalled at the end).
Question Is there a Jouanolou device $Y'\to \mathbb{P}^d$ with $\dim Y'<2d$?
In other words, is there a Jouanolou device for $\mathbb{P}^d$ which is more efficient dimension-wise than the classical one?
Lower bounds on $\dim Y'$ would also be welcome.
Note 1. The answer is clearly "No" if $d=1$.
Note 2.
While not strictly necessary for my question,   a quick way to describe the "standard" Jouanolou  device of $Y\to \mathbb{P}^d$ is to think of $\mathbb{P}^d$ as a quotient of algebraic groups $\mathrm{GL}_{d+1}/P$, where $P$ is the parabolic subgroup of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} A & * \\ 0 & * \end{bmatrix}$ with $A$ being $d\times d$, and taking  $Y=\mathrm{GL}_{d+1}/Q$, where $Q$ is the subgroup of $P$ consisting of matrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix} A & 0 \\ 0 & * \end{bmatrix}$ (isomorphic to $\mathrm{GL}_d\times \mathrm{GL}_1$). The morphism $f:Y\to \mathbb{P}^d$ is then the quotient map $\mathrm{GL}_{d+1}/Q\to \mathrm{GL}_{d+1}/P$, and $\mathrm{GL}_{d+1}/Q$ is affine by Matushima's Theorem (for instance).

The answer is no. Choose a prime $\ell$ not dividing the characteristic of your field $k$. An affine bundle $Y' \to \mathbb{P}^d$ would induce an isomorphism of $\ell$-adic cohomologies $H^{\bullet}(\mathbb{P}^d, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \cong H^{\bullet}(Y', \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$. Since the top cohomology $H^{2d}(\mathbb{P}^d,\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ is nonzero, it would follow that $H^{2d}(Y', \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \neq 0$. On the other hand, by Artin vanishing, we know that $H^{i}(Y',\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) =0$ for all $i > \mathrm{dim}(Y')$. This forces $\mathrm{dim}(Y')\geq 2d$.
